# HTTP Status 500 - Path friends does not start with a "/" character

Tags: java, jsp, struts, tiles, struts-1

**Below is the error:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Path friends does not start with a "/" character

type Exception report

message Path friends does not start with a "/" character

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path friends does not start with a "/" character
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1074)
org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:295)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:396)
org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:347)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

**`struts-config.xml` file:**

```xml
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/Link" parameter="method" type="com.vaannila.LinkAction">
        <forward name="friends" path="friends"/>
        <forward name="office" path="office"/>
    </action>
    <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
```

**`menu.jsp`:**

```xml
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="Link.do?method=friends" >Friends</a><br>
        <a href="Link.do?method=office" >The Office</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`baseLayout.jsp`:**

```xml
 <body>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td height="20%" colspan="2">
                    <tiles:insert attribute="header" ignore="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="250">
                    <tiles:insert attribute="menu" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <tiles:insert attribute="body" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="20%" colspan="2">
                    <tiles:insert attribute="footer" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`index.jsp`:**

```xml
<tiles:insert page="/baseLayout.jsp" flush="true">
    <tiles:put name="title" value="Tiles Example" />
    <tiles:put name="header" value="/header.jsp" />
    <tiles:put name="menu" value="/menu.jsp" />
    <tiles:put name="body" value="/body.jsp" />
    <tiles:put name="footer" value="/footer.jsp" />
</tiles:insert>
```

**`LinkAction.java`:**

```java
public class LinkAction extends DispatchAction {


/**
 * This is the Struts action method called on
 * http://.../actionPath?method=myAction1,
 * where "method" is the value specified in <action> element : 
 * ( <action parameter="method" .../> )
 */
public ActionForward friends(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm  form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    
    return mapping.findForward("friends");
}

/**
 * This is the Struts action method called on
 * http://.../actionPath?method=myAction2,
 * where "method" is the value specified in <action> element : 
 * ( <action parameter="method" .../> )
 */
public ActionForward office(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm  form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    
    return mapping.findForward("office");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `path` attribute should be absolute. According to the `struts-config_1.3.dtd`

> path - The module-relative path to the resources that is 
>                        encapsulated by the logical name of this ActionForward.
>                        This value should begin with a slash ("/") character.

But it is different if you use a tiles request processor. Put the following line to the `struts-config.xml`:

```
<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>
```

Comment: This didnt work either. friends.js is inserted as a tile in the body.jsp.

Comment: I don't understand, what is friends.js? Is it a javascript?

Comment: It is a simple jsp file   

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>More details about...</p>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: What is the version of struts?